# How to display content text with html tags and images in swift 3 ios

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview

I get text from `API` which contain `html tags` and `pictures`. How to display it, and where I need to display, I mean `UILabel` or `WebView`?
I try do with `NSAttributedString`, but not that I need.

**Platform iOS 9, Swift 3**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find way.
I do in `Info.plist`

> App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads -> YES

And image is displaying.

And code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
                data: (self.detailLabelText?.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!)!,
                options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                documentAttributes: nil)

   self.detailLabel.attributedText = attrStr
   self.detailLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
   self.detailLabel.contentMode = .scaleToFill
   self.detailLabel.font = UIFont(name: "PTSans-Narrow", size: 18.0)
}

detailLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
detailLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Info.plist was exactly what I was missing!

Comment: what about image content? it will be removed from the uilabel? or it will show?

Comment: @Zhanserik Best Answer :)

Comment: Can you help me with this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702924/how-to-render-image-using-html-css-using-flutter-to-create-ios-app

Comment: @jazzbpn Sorry, I have not experience with Flutter. Recommend write native apps.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the correct answer to this question. I'm stuck in something is there any way to avoid images in this data

Answer (score 2):

you can load html tags in webView as

```
 func loadHtmlCode() {
        let htmlCode = "<html><head><title>Wonderful web</title></head> <body><p>wonderful web. loading html code in <strong>UIWebView</strong></></body>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlCode, baseURL: nil)
    }
```

Comment: problem Webview (deprecated). anyone that have a good experiance with apple. because webkit have an navigation that is should not be allowed. because they will be lost in the page