# How to render image using HTML, CSS using flutter to create iOS-App?

Tags: html, ios, image, flutter, assets

I am **trying to create the PDF using HTML, CSS in flutter**. So, In some cases I have to render the asset image using html and css.

It is rendering in case of android by using the asset file location like (file:///android_asset/...) mentioned in the code below:

```
makeProfileImage() {
  return '<img src="file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/image_name.jpg">';
}
```

**How to get asset file path like (file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/...) in iOS?**

```
Future<void> printPdf() async {
  print('Print ...');
  await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
    return await Printing.convertHtml(
        format: PdfPageFormat.a4
            .applyMargin(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
        html: '<html><head>' +
            getRatingbarCss() +
            '<style>.checked {color: red;}</style>' +
            '</head><body style="margin:0;padding:0" bgcolor="white">' +
            makeProfileImage() +
            '<h2 style="color:black;">Star Rating</h2><span class="fa fa-star checked"/><span class="fa fa-star checked"/><span class="fa fa-star checked"/><span class="fa fa-star"/><span class="fa fa-star"/></body></html>');
  });
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pdf: ^1.3.17
  printing: ^2.0.0
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.4
```

Comment: Place your asset folder inside your Flutter project. Won't that help?

Comment: Yeah, I have image under asset folder and is already defined in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I don't think this is a flutter problem. because its about accessing assets from a web view if I understand this right.

Comment: There is a problem only with iOS because we can access the asset images in android. But in iOS I do not know how to access the asset image path in order to render image via HTML, CSS.

Comment: You can check the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787422/how-to-access-local-css-js-and-images-from-flutter-webview/59512920#59512920

Answer (score 3):

The current implementation, the FLTWebViewController and FLTWebViewFactory class in webview plugin don’t have access to registrar, so I changed their initWithMessenger method to initWithRegistrar. Now we have the answer to loading asset file in iOS webview:

```
NSString* key = [_registrar lookupKeyForAsset:url];
NSURL* nsUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:key withExtension:nil];
[_webView loadFileURL:nsUrl allowingReadAccessToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///"]];
```

as pull request: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1247/files

Example :

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <img src="image_name.jpg">
 </body>
</html>
```

Then create a assets folder in the root of the Flutter project :

```
assets:
  - assets/image_name.jpg
  - assets/htmlfile.html
```

Create the WebView
The dart code below creates the WebView and renders the local assets/htmlfile.html file.

```
  return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'assets/htmlfile.html',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        );
```

[Loading Local Assets in WebView in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/loading-local-assets-in-webview-in-flutter-b95aebd6edad)

Comment: how to use this code in flutter? NSString* key = [_registrar lookupKeyForAsset:url];
NSURL* nsUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:key withExtension:nil];
[_webView loadFileURL:nsUrl allowingReadAccessToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///"]];

Comment: @jazzbpn it is waiting to approve pull
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1247/files
you can edit 4 files at flutter plugin or wait to approve

Comment: Okay, I'm waiting.

Comment: Which four files do we have to edit and of which plugin? I do not find **FLTWebViewController** and **FLTWebViewFactory** classes in webview plugin. So, where are these files?

Comment: At path packages/webview_flutter/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h

Comment: I don't know, Sorry

Comment: We have not used **webview plugin** anywhere. So, is there any other option?

Comment: that's a good solution that sadly was not approved